# Add serial port to web page

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, serial-port

Is it possible to add a serial port control to a web application. I've tried creating one programmatically, but i have issues with the port staying open. I'm not sure how to fix that except by adding a serial port control somehow to the web page. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this task? Thanks in advance.

the following is the code I currently have:

```
public partial class LoadCellTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 
SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM3",9600,Parity.None,8,StopBits.One);

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
    serialPort1.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_ErrorReceived);

}

delegate void SerialDataReceivedDelegate(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e);
delegate void SerialErrorReceivedDelegate(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e);


protected void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Text = (serialPort1.ReadExisting());
   if (serialPort1.ReadExisting().Length == 0)
   {
       ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, TextBox1.Text);
       TextBox1.Text = "";
   }
}
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            button1.Text = "Start";
        }
        else
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
            button1.Text = "Stop";
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a serial port on the server, or on the client's PC?

Comment: your code seems to access the serial port of the server...

Comment: That would not work in a web app because the code for the serial port is code-behind, which runs on the server.  You'd need to create a WinForms app to use a SerialPort.  If you're doing ASP.NET Froms (as opposed to MVC) then writing a WinForms app is very similar to writing a web app, so you should be fine.

Comment: David, I've accomplished this task already in a windows form, but I was hoping to accomplish it in a web page because the data will need to be accessed on the web. The alternative to reading from the port via the web is doing a windows form and writing to a db and then reading the db in the web app. I wanna take out the middle step(DB).

Comment: then you will have to implement and embed an ActiveX control (which could access the serial port on the client, CUATION for security reasons!) into the web page...

Comment: That's the exact pattern we used with out coupon scanning software.  We had a WinForms app for scanning the barcode and form regular maintenance tasks, and an ASP.NET web app for reports.  We just created a menu option in the WinForms app to launch the web reports website.  Our users liked it quite a bit - they are pretty non-technical, and to them the reports website was just a part of the coupon scanning application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer...

The serial port code is server-side code.  You can't do it on the client with ASP.NET.

Creating an ActiveX or other fat client control is a load of work, and just not a good idea.

My recommendation would be to continue on with your WinForms app for the code where you need the scanner, and add a menu to it to enable you to launch a separate ASP.NET web app for the reports/data access.

If you want to make it more "seamless" for the users, you can add a form with a WebBrowser control that loads your report/data access site.  To them it will just be a "part of the application".

THAT SAID, depending on the device you have connected to the port, there may be an even simpler option.

One of our barcode scanners comes with software that just takes barcode data as it's scanned and pastes it into whatever open document has focus.  If you're working in Notepad, the scanned data is pasted into Notepad.  If you have a web app open, and the cursor in a text box, the data simply pastes in there.

It's a simpler option to implement, BUT it's harder on the users, because if they're not technical, they're going to call you wondering why the barcode beeps but doesn't populate the text box.  (The answer will be "Because your cursor isn't in the text box or the form doesn't have focus")

So I go back to recommendation #1.

Comment: I've gotten the data to paste in the text box. I have the data, i just can't update the control each time. I tried using a timer. The data is a constant stream...

Comment: There's got to be a way, b/c I'm awfully close to a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your code just accesses the serial port of the server since it is running on the server...

IF you really need to access the serial port on the client from a web app then you will need to use some technology that runs directly on the client... this could be an ActiveX control embedded into your web page...

I am really not sure perhaps a Silverlight application embedded into your web page could achieve this too...

Beware that doing so in a web page is a possible security problem !